# How do I call something trash in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot

For example, in English, if there is a game I dislike, I can call it trash:

> Fortnite is trash

However, I tried Google Translating this to French, I get:

> Fortnite est une poubelle

This does not really make sense, because *poubelle* means *trash can*. I am not calling Fortnite a trash can, I am calling Fornite trash.

What is the correct term to use to express disapproval by calling something trash in French?

Comment: For Francophones, note also that "trash" in this usage is highly marked as youth register

Comment: This is how I would say it: « c'est nul » or, more likely « c'est nullissime » or « c'est nase » (ou naze) or « c'est pourri ton jeu» or «c'est bidon! » or « ça vaut pas un clou ce jeu à la con! » or as jilliagre suggested « c'est de la daube » (the latter was trendy in my generation, it's probably a bit passé now.

Comment: Note that all of these derogatory terms are regional. You would definintely never hear nullissime, naze, pourri, bidon, "pas un clou", "à la con" or daube in Québec, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common way to say it would be:

> *[Fortnite, c'est de la merde.](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/fortnitecestdelamerde)* (can be *C'est de la marde* or *[Ça vaut pas de la marde](https://www.laparlure.com/terme/ca-vaut-pas-de-la-marde/)* in Québec).

otherwise:

> *[Fortnite, c'est de la daube.](https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-51-55256666-1-0-1-0-on-est-d-accord-que-fortnite-c-est-de-la-daube.htm)* (Possibly considered old-fashioned by younger generations.)

We wouldn't use or understand the usual "trash" translations (*poubelle* or *ordure*) in that context.

Comment: « c'est de la merde » is ruder than "it's trash". I say trash all the time, I never say merde... There is also a « quel jeu merdique » variation.

Comment: @Patrick Tu dois être la seule personne parlant français à ne jamais dire merde... :-)

Comment: ce n'est pas impossible!

Comment: "Trash" in this usage is pretty rude, even if its other senses are relatively neutral ("take out the trash", etc).

Comment: Isn't that saying "Fortnite is shit"? (which is a common way of saying it in english, just significantly more vulgar)

Comment: @Crazymoomin It is obviously the literal translation. I'm not sure about the level of vulgarity of *is shit* compared to *c'est de la merde* but the latter is in my opinion only slightly vulgar. [Gerald Darmanin](https://www.lavoixdunord.fr/864804/article/2020-09-14/), [Michel Sardou](https://www.gala.fr/l_actu/news_de_stars/leurovision-cest-de-la-merde-quand-mika-critiquait-le-concours_493760)

Comment: `c'est une ordure` peut-être

Comment: @hunter Pas vraiment, je n'ai jamais entendu *C'est une ordure* pour autre chose qu'une personne.

Comment: As someone from a younger generation, I can confirm "c'est de la daube" is considered old-fashioned :)

Answer (score 4):

Bonjour,
here are some other sentences one could hear or read :

> - Fortnite, c'est nul.
> - Fortnite, c'est (tout) pourri.
> - Fortnite, c'est moisi.

this one is used by younger people:

> - Fortnite, c'est tout pété.

this one is quite vulgar but widely used :

> - Fortnite, c'est à chier.

Comment: It's worth noting that regardless of the adjective used to degrade something, the construction "X est Y" (X is Y) seems less common in French than "X, c'est Y" (X, that's Y).